# TouchableWithoutFeedback only sometimes calls onPress on actual device while simulator works fine

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, ios-simulator, touchablewithoutfeedback

Just tested a simple UI on an actual iPhone that I had only built with the iOS simulator so far. Turns out that the iPhone only registers about 20% of my touches on buttons, while the simulator works just fine with 100% of the touches.

I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18235) to the repository and uploaded the code on Expo for anyone to try: https://snack.expo.io/@leonard91/bug-report

Possible reasons for that?

Comment: Attach the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @MattyK14 I prepared an Expo Snack to try it out. It doesn't work in Expo as well. Posted the link above.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to touch area because when we use simulator we click using the mouse pointer, but in the real device, we click using touch, so increase touch by giving width and height to **touchableWithoutFeedback**.

Comment: You mean the `hitSlop` property?